# Page number with a symbol

Tags: symbols, page-numbering

I am looking to put the page number inside the atom symbol, Is this possible?
I have been looking for information on the web, but I can't find anything similar.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144193/how-do-i-put-a-die-roll-at-the-top-of-each-page

Answer (score 1):

You can use the atom symbol from [How to draw a symbol on a TikZ node that can be reused](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349960/how-to-draw-a-symbol-on-a-tikz-node-that-can-be-reused), adapted to print the page counter inside of the node.

Then, using `fancyhdr`, you can redefine the footer to use the new macro instead of the standard number (see for example [Page numbers only on even pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443115/page-numbers-only-on-even-pages)). The table of contents is produced using the standard numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bottom=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\def\science{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle, draw, minimum size=10mm] at (0,0) {\tiny\arabic{page}};
\foreach \ang in {0,120,240}
  \draw[rotate around={\ang:(0,0)}] (0,0) ellipse (4.5mm and 1.5mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}%
\fancyfoot[C]{\science}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Lipsum}
\lipsum[1-100]
\section{New section}
\end{document}
```

[image]